# javascript 'build' (create) a hyperlink button by adding elements innerHTML values

Tags: javascript

**Note 1**: I do not own the website, so I can't change the source code by edit.
**Note 2**: I need PURE JavaScript (NOT jquery) solution. (please don't ask 'why not?' or try to suggest me to use it.)

There is a (random) page which has a table in it. Table has (ofcorse) table data cells. It looks something like this:

```
<div>

    <table class="mytable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><label>First Name:</label></td>
                <td>John</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span>Last Name:</span></td>
                <td>Smith</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>City:</label></td>
                <td>BRONX</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>State:</strong></td>
                <td>NY</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Go to this website:&nbsp;</td>
                <td><span><a href="https://somesite.com/">https://somesite.com/</a></span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

As you can see, last cell (table data) asks me to go to 'somesite[dot]com' where I should search for some person by filling in a form (on somesite) with 'First Name, Last Name, City and State'. Now, 'interesting' thing here, is when I finally press the 'search' button on that 'somesite[dot]com, my browser address ends up like this:

```
https://somesite.com/find/search-results-table?city=BRONX&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&addressType=ANY&state=NY
```

here is one more time, so you can see what I mean:

https://somesite.com/find/search-results-table?city=**BRONX**&first_name=**John**&last_name=**Smith**&addressType=ANY&state=**NY**

So, as you see, search result page generated a link by using a first name, last name, city and state as part of the link (by pulling it from a database).

What I want is to re-create that hyperlink on the first website where I got that information, and without going to 'somesite[dot]com] to 'waste time' to fill-in all required fields (first name, last name, city, and state). I want to create a hyper link with a button which, when I press it will directly open a somesite[dot]com search result for that person I should be looking for by 'manualy filling in given information'.

Now, I can (I know how to) create a button by using a 'createElement'. I can also add an id to it, and I can add that button to the div element that holds a table (from my example) but ussing 'appendChild'.

I searched here and on other page by using google, and I can't find how to 'copy' innerHTML or 'textNode' from a specific element and then use that (I guess) variable to 'put it' in a 'text patern' which will, at the end create a 'working' hyperlink that I can attack to the button. So once I press the button I will go straight to the somesite, but instead of filling in required information I will already end up on the search result page for that person I should be searching for by manually typing in.

I can't figureout how to use javascript to do that. :(

I hope I've managed to explain what I need.

Thanks in advance for everyone who try to help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the userscript manager of your choice (such as Tampermonkey), and then use it to alter the anchor link on the first site:

```js
const secondTds = [...document.querySelectorAll('.mytable td:nth-child(2)')];
const linkTd = secondTds.pop();
const queryStringValues = secondTds.map(td => td.textContent);
const params = new URLSearchParams();
const paramNames = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'city', 'state'];
queryStringValues.forEach((val, i) => {
  params.set(paramNames[i], val);
});
params.set('addressType', 'ANY');
const url = 'https://somesite.com/find/search-results-table?' + params.toString();
console.log(url);
linkTd.querySelector('a').href = url;
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="mytable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><label>First Name:</label></td>
        <td>John</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Last Name:</span></td>
        <td>Smith</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>City:</label></td>
        <td>BRONX</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>State:</strong></td>
        <td>NY</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Go to this website:&nbsp;</td>
        <td><span><a href="https://somesite.com/">https://somesite.com/</a></span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: CertainPerformance, thanks for a fast respond. Yes, I'm using Tampermonkey with FF v56. I've tried to use your code, but I can't figureout, once I create and 'append' a button, how to add a resulting hyperlink from your script to that button, so that I can just click on it and get redirected to a site with search results. Can you help a bit more? (newbie here)

Comment: My script changes the `href` of the `a` in the table - just click the `a`. If you want a separate element, then you could do something like `const newA = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('a')); newA.href = url; newA.textContent = 'new link';`

Comment: CertainPerformance, thanks again for your explanation. Your idea of changing a 'href' of the 'a' (instead of making an extra button) is even better. I tested your code by using https://jsfiddle.net/ssssda9d/
and it works at jsfiddle, but when I apply it at my tampermonkey script it doesn't do anything (it doesn't change a hyperlink once I click on it or do a mouse-over). I even set it to be 'global' by setting '// @include *. Still doesn't work :( Any more idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As you can see by running the live snippet, the code *works* and corresponds to your question, so if there's some other issue, it's outside of the scope of the question posted so far. Check your browser console for errors if you haven't already.

Comment: CertainPerformance, thanks for another fast reply. I'll mark your answer as a solution and then try to figureout why it doesn't work at my side.
Thanks again for your help!